# SQL query: Multiple SQL joins for multiple column checks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am new to this forum. Except for basics, I didn't have much of exposure to more advanced SQL queries. Hence I'm seeking any advice that can help me understand better the following problem.

Let's say I have two tables (`A` and `B`). The primary keys are `A.id` and `B.id`. In addition, let's say, table `B` has two more fields, `B.a_key` (foreign key for `A.id`) and `B.feature`. Therefore, table `B` may(usually) have more entries since multiple rows in `B` may be pointing to a single `A.id`.

I have a query that is in the following format:

```
[{B.feature=1}, {B.feature=0}, {B.feature=3}]
```

Return ALL `A.id`that have at least 3 entries in table B and those 'feature' values are (1, 0, 3)

```
[{B.feature=0}]
```

Return ALL `A.id` that have at least 1 entry in B with the'feature' value (0)

```
[{B.feature=0}, {B.feature=2}, {B.feature=5}, {B.feature=6}]
```

Return ALL `A.id` that have at least 4 entries in table B and those 'feature' values are (0,2,5,6)

```
[]
```

Trivial case: Return ALL `A.id` (no need to filter)
...

Thanks.

I was thinking of preparing an SQL statement with as many JOINS as B entries and then filtering them in the where clause, but I think I'm catching more than needed.

E.g sample 1:

```sql
select distinct A.id 
from A
left join B b on A.id = b.a_key 
left join B bb on A.id = bb.a_key
left join B bbb on A.id = bbb.a_key
where (b.feature = 1 and bb.feature = 0 and bbb.feature = 3);
```

Edit 1:
As per [Jonas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18794826/jonas-metzler) suggestion, I'm adding a data sample and expected results.

```
INSERT INTO A (id) values (1);
INSERT INTO A (id) values (2);
INSERT INTO A (id) values (3);

INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1000, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1001, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1002, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1003, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1004, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1005, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1006, 1, 6);


INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2000, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2001, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2002, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2003, 2, 3);


INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (3000, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (3001, 3, 1);
```

`[{b.feature=0}, {b.feature=1}]`
Select statement should return all 3 IDs from table `A` since there are at least 2 entries in table `B` (with feature values 0 and 1) for every ID from `A`.

`[{b.feature=0}, {b.feature=1}, {b.feature=3}]`
Select statement should return only id=1 and id=2 from table `A`, since in table `B` we don't have `b.feature=3` and `b.a_key=3`.

Comment: Describing an issue in words is generally not bad, but the more text you write, the more chances exist people will understand it incorrect. Could you please show some sample data and expected result as tables?

Comment: `... LEFT JOIN B on A.id = b.A_key WHERE b.feature in ( 0, 1, 3)`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver. Thanks, I assume this will include a row if `b.feature` is any of those in set (0,1,3)? `b.feature` with the same `b.a_key` must be at least all 3 (0,1,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate the values for a given `a_key`(`a.id`). Then use compare the aggregated array to an array of the desired id's.

```
create table a(id integer);
INSERT INTO A (id) values (1);
INSERT INTO A (id) values (2);
INSERT INTO A (id) values (3);
create table b (id integer, a_key integer, feature integer);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1000, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1001, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1002, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1003, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1004, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1005, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (1006, 1, 6);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2000, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2001, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2002, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (2003, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (3000, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_key, feature) values (3001, 3, 1);


SELECT
    a_key AS id,
    agg
FROM (
    SELECT
        a_key,
        array_agg(feature) AS agg
    FROM
        b
    WHERE
        feature IN (0, 1)
    GROUP BY
        a_key) AS a
WHERE
    ARRAY[0, 1] = a.agg
ORDER BY
    id

id |  agg  
----+-------
  3 | {0,1}
  1 | {0,1}
  2 | {0,1}



SELECT
    a_key AS id,
    agg
FROM (
    SELECT
        a_key,
        array_agg(feature) AS agg
    FROM
        b
    WHERE
        feature IN (0, 1, 3)
    GROUP BY
        a_key) AS a
WHERE
    ARRAY[0, 1, 3] = a.agg
ORDER BY 
    id;

 id |   agg   
----+---------
  1 | {0,1,3}
  2 | {0,1,3}
```

Comment: [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver), Thanks for the pointers. So, there is no need to cross reference data with table `A` since everything is already in `B`?

It seems it works. The only thing I changed is to compare aggregated results as subsets since I don't care about the order.

```
WHERE
    a.agg @> array[0,1,3]
```
instead of 
```
WHERE
    ARRAY[0, 1, 3] = a.agg
```

Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: On a related note, my changes still don't cover duplicates `[true, true] @> [true]` evaluates to True (and it shouldn't since there are 2 elements on the left side) since it's a subset and not a subsequence check.

I was thinking of counting occurrences to handle duplicates and then comparing them with the `>=` array operator. 

But again, this approach is not general enough to handle other types of comparison for example larger than `[10, 20, 3] >= [11, 10, 1]` should evaluate as true.

Comment: You are asking a different question now, so create a new question that addresses what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I opened a more generic question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634180/postgresql-find-elements-that-have-enough-row-entries-to-satisfy-query